# Webpack doesn't minify CSS and JS into single line and showing comments

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack, minify

I am running `npm run build` command and I am expecting it to minify my `jss` and `css` files which does but the code is still spread over multiple line and including comments. How to tell `webpack` to compress it to single line and remove comments?

this is how build command looks into `package.json`

```
"build": "npm run buildsprite && webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --colors",
```

this is optimization chunk from `webpack.config.prod.js`

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      extractComments: false,
    }),
  ],
},
```

Comment: Add `minimize: true,` to the `optimization` object. Here's the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/), your `webpack.config.prod.js` should look something like this:

```
optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      extractComments: false,
    }),
  ],
},
```

You Need `minimize: true` so that webpack can actually Minify using Terser